# Adding a new domain model in Grails

Tags: grails, model-view-controller

So I need to add a new domain file and corresponding controller to a Grails Project to create a prototype. I use this command:

grails create-domain-class com.grio.moment.MyTest

It creates MyTest.groovy successfully in the desired path. Also created this controller manually called MyTestController.

My question is now do I need to do additional configuration for database mapping or it automatically completes the configuration after I used the command in order to create the Domain Class?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to provide any additional configuration for database mapping.  If the class is defined under `grails-app/domain/` Grails will impose default mappings automatically.

If you want to customize the mapping you can do that by defining a static `mapping` block in your domain class.

```
// grails-app/domain/demo/Person.groovy
package demo

class Person {
    String firstName
    String lastName

    static mapping = {
        // by default the table name would be 'person', this changes that...
        table 'people'
    }
}
```

See http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#ormdsl for more details.